# How to filter with OR in Xero API?

Tags: xero-api

I am integrating Contacts in Xero with BC. Per default, Contacts in Xero have ContactNumber set to null. But when clearing it is empty (" "). Therefore, when connecting a contact in BC with a contact in Xero, I need to filter on something like this:

ContactStatus == "ACTIVE" && ( ContactNumber == null OR ContactNumber == " ")

But this does not work, does anyone know how to apply a nested or filter? Thank you in advance.

{
"ErrorNumber": 16,
"Type": "QueryParseException",
"Message": "Syntax error"
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not see any issue with the query and when I tried it with API Explorer it worked fine.

[API Explorer query for GET /Contacts?where=ContactStatus == "ACTIVE" && (ContactNumber == null OR ContactNumber == " ")](https://api-explorer.xero.com/accounting/contacts/getcontacts?query-where=ContactStatus%20%3D%3D%20%22ACTIVE%22%20%26%26%20%28ContactNumber%20%3D%3D%20null%20OR%20ContactNumber%20%3D%3D%20%22%20%22%29)

Comment: Just realized that the issue was unrelated to the filtering and an URL issue. Thanks.